# my list is not showing while i click on the button

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, viewmodel

Actually i couldn't find any error here. I think i m missing something here. this filtersbutton is not working. Your help will be appreciated. Thank you

## This is my fragment.class

```
    sortByLeastExpensive = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sort_by_least_expensive);
    sortByMostExpensive = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sort_by_most_expensive);
    sortByMostRecent = rootView.findViewById(R.id.sort_by_most_recent);

    applyFiltersBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.apply_filters_btn);

    sortByLeastExpensive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //set the filter; or call the viewmodel to set the filter?
           mViewModel.sortBy.setValue(getResources().getString(R.string.sort_rooms_ascending));
        }
    });
    sortByMostExpensive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mViewModel.sortBy.setValue(getResources().getString(R.string.sort_rooms_descending));
        }
    });
    sortByMostRecent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          mViewModel.sortBy.setValue("sort_most_recent");
       }
    });


    return rootView;
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(FilterRoomsViewModel.class);

  mViewModel.getSortBy().observe(this, Observer -> {
        Log.i("Viewmodel", "Viewmodel ,sortby: " + mViewModel.sortBy.getValue());
    });


    applyFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           FilterRoomsRepository roomsRepository = new FilterRoomsRepository();
           roomsRepository.getFilteredRooms(mViewModel.sortBy.getValue());
           
        }
   });
}
```

### This is viewmodel.class

i have updated my viewmodel.class. now its showing me another error on fragment.class

```
public FilterRoomsViewModel(Application application){
    super();

FilterRoomsRepository filterRoomsRepository = new FilterRoomsRepository(application);
}
public MutableLiveData<String> getRooms(){
    if (rooms==null){
        rooms = new MutableLiveData<String>();
    }
return rooms;
}
    public LiveData<String> getSortBy() {
if (sortBy == null){
    sortBy = new MutableLiveData<String>();
}
    return sortBy;
}
```

#### this is repository.class

```
    if(sortyBy.equals("ascending")){
        Log.i("Sort by", "Rooms sorted in ascending order");
        filterQuery.orderByAscending("roomRentalAmount");
    }else if (sortyBy.equals("descending")){
        Log.i("Sort by", "Rooms sorted in descending order");
        filterQuery.orderByDescending("roomRentalAmount");
    }else {
        filterQuery.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
    }

    filterQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if(e == null){
                //success
                Log.i("Rooms", "Filtered rooms, " + objects.get(0).getObjectId());
                rooms.setValue(objects);
            }else{
                //error, handle accordingly
                Log.e("Error", "Error filtering, " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
    Log.i("Rooms", "Live data rooms, " + rooms.getValue());
    return rooms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean that its not showing? It's not showing in the ui or in logs? Because when you call getFilteredRooms you don't do anything with the result.
What i would suggest is to move the repository call to the viewModel, so that instead of calling getFilteredRooms in the fragment, you would call sth like viewModel.getFilteredRooms and then, in the viewmodel, you call the repository and you use the result to set the value of the livedata.
Then, in the fragment you just need to observe this variable and based on that you update the ui. By doing so, you separate the logic (viewmodel and repository) from the ui part (fragment).

Here is a good tutorial on how to code with mvvm pattern: https://medium.com/@er.ankitbisht/mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-kotlin-google-jetpack-f02ec7754854

Comment: Can you please do this for me? I will be thankful to you. Because I newbie here.

Comment: I added the link in the answer to the tutorial. For a beginner I would suggest to read about mvvm first: how to divide your ui from app logic, how to work with coroutines etc.

Comment: sir, i have updated my viewmodel. now its showing me this error. **Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class .viewmodel.FilterRoomsViewModel** in this line `mViewModel.getSortBy().observe(this, Observer -> {
        Log.i("Viewmodel", "Viewmodel ,sortby: " + mViewModel.sortBy.getValue());
    });`

Comment: Please create another question, because it's a different question. Also, dont forget to upvote the answer if i helped ;)